# Prove that an algorithm that generates a stable set of a graph can be used in any graph for generating a stable set of maximum cardinal.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $A$ an algorithm with polynomial time, which receives an graph $G$ and returns
the stable set $S_A(G)$ of $G$ with the property:

$$ \alpha(G) - |S_A(G)| \le  k, $$ for a constant $k\in N$

Prove that $A$ can be used for determining , in polynomial time, a stable set of maximum cardinal in a given graph.

I have tried by taking $T$ isomorphic copies of the graph and I have tried to extend the graph. But I get stuck at this point, can you give me some hints?

Comment: maybe k exists, but not any?

Comment: @kotomord Sorry, $k$ was actually a constant. I have fixed this mistake.

Comment: Using "|" where "\mid" should be used instead is a frequent error on this site, but this was the opposite mistake: "\mid" was used where "|" was appropriate. Notice how conspicuously different they look: $$ \alpha(G) - |S_A(G)| \le  k, $$ $$ \alpha(G) - \mid S_A(G)\mid \le  k, $$ Notice the lack of space to the left of the minus sign and to the left of the less-than-or-equal-to sign in the incorrect version. (And also the larger spaces surrounding $S_A(G)$.) There is a reason why it works that way, which should become clear if you think about it for a moment. $\qquad$

Comment: Is $k$ a fixed number or can we pick whatever $k$ we want?

Comment: @AydinGerek $k$ is said to be a constant.

Answer (score 3):

Create G1 as the k+1 copies of G.