# Stable set of maximum cardinal

Tags: graph-theory

Let A an algorithm with polynomial time, which receives an graph G and returns the stable set SA(G) of G with the property:

α(G)−|SA(G)|≤k,
for a constant k∈N

Prove that A can be used for determining , in polynomial time, a stable set of maximum cardinal in a given graph.

Can you help me ?
I need all solution....

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2003653/prove-that-an-algorithm-that-generates-a-stable-set-of-a-graph-can-be-used-in-an/  - duplicate?